# Can a Geopackage Boolean field contain a NULL value?

Tags: geopackage, null, boolean

QGIS 3.24.3.  When I create a Geopackage Boolean field, the default display is the word *false*, displayed in italics.  Likewise, if I calculate the Boolean field = NULL, they also display as an italic *false*.

However, if I calculate the Boolean field = false, the result is a non-italic false.  Finally, if I calculate the field = true, the result is a non-italic true.

In summary, here's what I notice:

- *false* means NULL
- false means false
- true means true

Have I got this correct?  Screenshot attached.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

In response to the comment by @Vince, I performed the following attribute selection test:

test_field IS NULL: only *false* records selected
test_field: only true records selected
NOT test_field: only false records selected

Which supports the idea that *false* really means NULL.

Comment: It should be basic ternary logic, except it's NULL means NULL (the *false* is a UI artifact). Have you tested how many rows are returned by `test_field IS NULL`, `test_field` and `NOT test_field`?

Comment: Testing is a great idea (d'oh, why didn't I think of that?!).  OP edited.

Comment: I agree with you that *false* is a UI artifact.  Can you please cite a source for that?  If possible I'd like to log a bug report or enhancement request to the proper authorities, because NULL should appear to the user as the word NULL, not an italicized *false* - there's the obvious confusion, plus it's just bad feng shui!

Comment: Please file and link a issue!

Comment: Here is a ticket that concerns this issue: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44556

Answer (score 3):

By the GeoPackage standard the Boolean values are stored as zero or one:

> A boolean value representing true or false. Stored as SQLite INTEGER
> with value 0 for false or 1 for true.

So at the SQLite level and when the type of the field is checked from the CREATE TABLE definition

- NULL means NULL
- 0 means FALSE
- 1 means TRUE

Comment: I agree that it is possible for a Boolean to contain a NULL.  But here's the problem: NULL is not displayed with the text NULL.  Rather, NULL is displayed with the text *false* which is just plain confusing!  As @Vince has pointed out *false* appears to be a UI artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a GeoPackage boolean field can be empty/`NULL`.

QGIS currently (3.34) shows them as grey and italized string "*false*".

It is currently (3.34) not possible to reset a boolean field to be empty in the attribute form or attribute table. One can reset them using the Field Calculator and the expression "`NULL`".

A QGIS bug tracking this issue is at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44556