# Setting a Boolean field to be empty

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, editing, null

I have a layer with a Boolean field called `bool`.
I can set the field value to NULL, e.g. using the Field Calculator.

When printed via Python, the values are correctly shown as `None`:

```
>>> layer = iface.activeLayer()
>>> [f.__geo_interface__ for f in layer.getFeatures()]
[{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'bool': None}, 'geometry': ...}]
```

In the attribute table they are shown in grey, indicating that they are NULL too:

[image]

If I edit one of them to be true, the `true` value is correctly shown in the attribute table:

[image]

Via Python I also get the correct value: `{'bool': True}`

Now how can I reset the value to be blank/`NULL`/`None` again *via the attribute table or the attribut form*?

In the attribute table I get a checkbox that I can toggle. There is no reset icon or anything like that:

[image]

In the attribute form there is a similar checkbox, also no way to reset the value:

[image]

I am not looking for workarounds in any way, I want to know if there is a way for users to reset a boolean field to be empty using the attribute table or attribute form.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44556 this is not possible in QGIS at the moment and that is considered to be a bug.

There was also some related discussion of other confused users in [Can a Geopackage Boolean field contain a NULL value?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436400/can-a-geopackage-boolean-field-contain-a-null-value)